# Printing Long values with toString in Java

Tags: java, long-integer, tostring

I have a question about printing a long value with the toString method.

My code is:

```
public class LinkedLargeInteger {

    private class Node {

    private int data;
    private long dat;
    private Node next;

    private Node(int data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    private Node(int data) {
        this(data, null);
    }

    private Node() {
        data = 0;
        next = null;
    }

    private Node(long dat, Node next) {
        this.dat = dat;
        this.next = next;
    }

    private Node(long dat) {
        this(dat, null);
    }

}

private Node head;
private Node tail;
private int size;
private String largeString;
private int largeInt;
private long largeLong;

public LinkedLargeInteger(long largeLong) {
    String s = Long.toString(largeLong);
    head = new Node();
    tail = head;
    size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        tail.next = new Node(Long.parseLong(s), null);
        tail = tail.next;
        size++;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Node current = head.next;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
        builder.append(i + 1);
        current = current.next;
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedLargeInteger numLong = new LinkedLargeInteger(100000000000L);
    System.out.println(numLong);
}
}
```

I have implemented a linked list with my Node class and want to print out a long value with my constructor.
When I print a long value out in main, it gives my an entirely different number than what I entered as an argument. 
Does someone have any idea what my problem could be?

Comment: Currently your `toString` method will return all the numbers from 1 to size-1 (i.e `123...size-1`). If you want to append the content of the Nodes, use `builder.append(current.data);`

Comment: because it has a toString ?

Comment: all your nodes have the same value, too.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to builder.append(current.data); but now the long that prints out is just a bunch of zeros.

Comment: @user2713971 I don't know what do you want to print and what is the expected output.

Comment: So I changed the call to                                  LinkedLargeInteger numLong = new LinkedLargeInteger(987938645L);        And it just prints out zeros. It needs to print whatever number I put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix the constructor:

```
public LinkedLargeInteger(long largeLong) {
    String s = Long.toString(largeLong);
    head = new Node();
    tail = head;
    size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    // You were putting the whole number, not the digits
        tail.next = new Node(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i))), null); // <<==
        tail = tail.next;
        size++;
    }
}
```

And the toString:

```
public String toString() {
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Node current = head.next;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
        builder.append(current.dat); // <<==
        current = current.next;
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```